# Setting innerHTML string produces syntax errors

Tags: javascript, html

I've looked on here and most say that its escape problems so I think I too am at fault of this. I look on google and most have example of replace the text of one div with another etc.. here I want to replace the default content of " mainMidSec" with what I have on the if statement in the .js

I'm trying to test something out for a mobile site...but I'm getting syntax errors. I'm almost positive it has to do with quotes etc...I've tried outer double inner single quotes and the other way around and its not taking it.

Here is the code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var screenW = document.getElementById('mainMidSec');

if ((screen.width<=800) && (screen.height<=800))
{

screenW.innerHTML = '<video width="500" height="400" controls poster="imgs/vidPosterImgSMALLER.jpg">
    <source src="videos/mp4-video-versions/2010reel_MP4.mp4">
    <p> Your current web browser is out of date . Please update it wont you...pretty please?</p>
</video>'

}

</script>
```

Any ideas / suggestions / knowledge bombs you guys drop on me I'll gladly and humbly accept!

Comment: if new to javascript I would advise you to look into javascript frameworks. A very popular one is jquery.com

Comment: thanks Alfred. i am new to .JS and i mean i understand it but im a super noob! so i was/am trying to learn the basics b4 i went to the framwork.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't split a string across several lines.

Put the string on a single line:

```
screenW.innerHTML = '<video width="500" height="400" controls poster="imgs/vidPosterImgSMALLER.jpg"><source src="videos/mp4-video-versions/2010reel_MP4.mp4"><p> Your current web browser is out of date . Please update it wont you...pretty please?</p></video>';
```

Or make each line a separate string:

```
screenW.innerHTML = '<video width="500" height="400" controls poster="imgs/vidPosterImgSMALLER.jpg">' +
  '<source src="videos/mp4-video-versions/2010reel_MP4.mp4">' +
  '<p> Your current web browser is out of date . Please update it wont you...pretty please?</p>' +
  '</video>';
```

Answer (score 2):

In javascript, you cannot have line breaks inside a string. Try:

```
screenW.innerHTML = '<video width="500" height="400" controls poster="imgs/vidPosterImgSMALLER.jpg"><source src="videos/mp4-video-versions/2010reel_MP4.mp4"> <p> Your current web browser is out of date . Please update it wont you...pretty please?</p></video>'
```

Also, take a look at [CSS Media Queries](http://css-tricks.com/6731-css-media-queries/), which are the recommended way to deal with alternate layouts for mobile devices.

Comment: long story short, i went for this because theres a huge flash file in the main site, and i want to replace it with a smaller one on the server depending on screen size. will media queries also do this? thanks

Comment: No. I think the best way to do that is server-side, with php, asp or whatever. If you must use only html and javascript, you have to use js. I'm afraid in this case the browser *may* initiate a request for the big file before the replacement finishes.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
screenW.innerHTML = '<video width="500" height="400" controls poster="imgs/vidPosterImgSMALLER.jpg">
<source src="videos/mp4-video-versions/2010reel_MP4.mp4">
<p> Your current web browser is out of date . Please update it wont you...pretty please?</p>
```

'

To :

```
screenW.innerHTML = '<video width="500" height="400" controls poster="imgs/vidPosterImgSMALLER.jpg"> ' +
'<source src="videos/mp4-video-versions/2010reel_MP4.mp4"> ' +
'<p> Your current web browser is out of date . Please update it wont you...pretty please?</p> ' +
```

''